# How to make DrawString work for negative y scale factor?

Tags: winforms, drawstring, scaletransform

Working on a private stock chart where I use a rendering rectangle with an origin at lower left and inverted y axis, scale factor y is negative. Y axis ticks render nicely but drawing text (drawstring) is where I run into problems.

```
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(_color))
            using (Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16))
            using (SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
            {
                pen.Width = 1F / e.Graphics.DpiX;
                foreach (float tick in this.TimeSeriesPanelControl.YTicks)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, right, tick, right + 10, tick);
                    // this is not producing text to the right of the tick that renders properly.
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tick.ToString("F2"), drawFont, drawBrush, right + 15, tick);
                }
            }
```

I have seen that the text is upside down caused by the negative scale factor on the y coordinate.

The question is how to make drawstring render the text to the right of the tick?

Comment: Where are the transformation Matrices? How are they applied (in which order). What does *negative scale factor* mean? This is wrong: `pen.Width = 1F / e.Graphics.DpiX;`

Comment: I mean, did you apply `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, [Canvas.Height]);` and
`e.Graphics.ScaleTransform([ScaleX], [ScaleY]);`, or did you multiply two Matrices and then set `e.Graphics.Transform = [Mul-Matrices]`?

Comment: Initially


>e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
>e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, -1);

Then later in OnPaint when min and max y and origin y are known:

>e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(70, originY);
>e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, scaleY);
            
That does render curves and y ticks nicely.
Problem is with the tick labels as indicated.

Comment: Initially  
  
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, this.ClientRectangle.Height);  
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, -1);  
  
  
Then later in OnPaint when min and max y and origin y are known:  
    
  
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(70, originY);
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, scaleY);
  
  
That does render curves and y ticks nicely.  
Problem is with the tick labels as indicated.

Comment: fixed it by removing all transforms and transforming everything myself which leads to a more to the point solution